# Select oldest table row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where I want to track rest api requests by request time and always to send the oldest updated keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    api_requested_at timestamp without time zone
)
```

Example:

```
select * from processed_words where api_requested_at // get the oldest row
```

How I can select the oldest row into the table using `api_requested_at` column value?

Comment: You don't need a `WHERE` clause. You can just order the data instead. `ORDER BY api_requested_at ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: See [ORDER BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html) and [LIMIT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html). Or read literally any postgres tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM processed_words ORDER BY api_requested_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query will sort by api_requested_at in descending order and output the first entry.